# DSpace7.4 UI is only working in localhost, it's not working through IP (even after IP set in configuration file)

Tags: dspace

I have installed DSpace7.4 in Ubuntu22.04 LTS.
Installed Backend & Frontend (both), Backend & Solr both are working through IP, but the Frontend is not working through IP in DSpace7.4.

I have installed DSpace 7.2 before couple of months, but it's working fine through IP, I did the same configuration in DSpace 7.4 but somehow it's not working.

it's only open in http://localhost:4000 but not through http://{IP-ADDRESS}:4000

If anyone facing the same kind of issue? also share your feedback/suggestions.

Regards
Bhavesh

dspace.cfg  - both the URL has the IP
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpqTR.jpg)

config.yml
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdod7.png)

solr - webpage
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxh9w.png)

HAL Browser
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mkgta.png)

UI:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ozeal.png)

Answer (score 0):

maybe your dspace-angular.json is missing the correct information, I was facing the same problem as you, and had totally forgot to change the configuration on the json file for production. Hope it helps!

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
           "name": "dspace-angular",
           "cwd": "/var/opt/dspace-angular-dspace-7.5",
           "script": "dist/server/main.js",
           "env": {
              "NODE_ENV": "production",
   "DSPACE_REST_SSL": "true",
   "DSPACE_REST_HOST": "YOUR.IP.OR.URL",
   "DSPACE_REST_PORT": "443",
   "DSPACE_REST_NAMESPACE": "/server"
           }
        }
    ]
}
```